# Not able to find ebay seller id of a product

Tags: ebay-api

I am using ebay API to fetch some product information about particular keywords, I am able to perform the search using API and I am also able to get details of the particular product, what I am not able to get is the seller id of this product, if I get that I can fetch the seller information using [GetUserProfile](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetUserProfile.html) please help as I am trying to find it since last few hours. Following is the url I am hitting to fetch the product data:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=JSON&appid=My-app-Id&siteid=0&version=515&ItemID=172005320973
```

Comment: Which API operation are you calling to find product information as that will determine how you can get the seller id.

Comment: @DavidT.Sadler I have edited the question and added the link I am hitting to fetch the product info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure a quick response [GetSingleItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) will, by default, only return a small subset of the information available to describe an item. To instruct the API to return more data you can make use of the [IncludeSelector](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Request.IncludeSelector) field in your request. By setting the value of this field to *Details* the API will return information such as the seller.

http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=JSON&appid=My-app-Id&siteid=0&version=515&ItemID=172005320973&IncludeSelector=Details

The value found in the response field [Item.Seller.UserID](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Response.Item.Seller.UserID) can then be passed to GetUserProfile.